# Game development, storing items and achievements data

Tags: database, storage

I am creating a game. Currently on Android but it might be ported to another platforms. It has these features :

- Buyable items: characters, accessories, powerups, etc.
- Achievements

A buyable item has a name, price, description, and an image icon (probably from sprite).
An Achievement has a name, requirements to achieve, and rewards.

For example I have 50 buyable items and 25 achievements.
My question is, where should I store these objects data ?

Should I write them into a JSON file like this then load them into code ?

```
"items" : [
    {"name":"Health Potion", "type":"usable", "price":500, "description":"", "imageSrc": "potion.jpg"},
    {"name":"Adventurer", "type":"character", "price":5000, "description":"", "imageSrc": "adv.jpg"},
],
"achievements" : [
    {"name":"Buy 10 times", "action":"buy", "action_count":10, "reward":"500|gold"},
    {"name":"Buy 100 times", "action":"buy", "action_count":100, "reward":"5000|gold"}
]
```

If not JSON, should I put them to :

- Binary file format, encrypted (harder to crack)
- Database

Or maybe it would be better to hard code them ?

```
buyableItems[0] = new UsableItem("Health Potion", 500);
buyableItems[1] = new Character("Adventurer", 5000);

achievements[0] = new Achievement("Buy 10 times", "buy", 10, "500|gold");
achievements[1] = new Achievement("Buy 100 times", "buy", 100, "5000|gold");
```

Comment: This is highly opinion-based question. Any solution will work.

Comment: @keltar Thanks for mentioning that any solution will work. I always have a feeling that a specific solution is "bad", and still searching for a "best" solution.

Comment: well none of them is surely better than another, so I suggested use whatever you like more. Changing format alone wouldn't protect your data anyway. E.g. your 'purchases', if they aren't local, surely would be verified on server side, and only thing that could be 'cracked' is what amount it displays on screen, not how it will actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what's important to you, and how 'valuable' these achievements and items are.
If you are building a freemium game with purchasable items, you may want it secure, or you may not care.

It also depends on how frequent you decide to maintain and update these items/achievements.

It also depends on if other people will be maintaining and/or building these achievements.
A game designer perhaps will find it easier editing a JSON file rather than digging through source-code.

If you want portable maintainability - go JSON.
If your using things like external editors - go JSON.
If your doing it yourself, just hardcode them.

I know for a fact many games with detailed maps/levels use JSON, then parse the JSON in to build the world. There are many advantages to this. But it sounds like your specific case is not as complicated as this.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I think I will use JSON.